# what difference does it make if i dont use pointer?

Tags: c++

I was watching a video on youtube, how to do casting in c++? 
As this is static casting I just want to know what will happen if I don't use pointers.

```
class Base{};
class Derived1: public Base {};
class Derived2: public Base{};

int main(){
    Derived d1;
    Derived d2;

    Base *bp1=static_cast<Base*>(&d1);
    Base *bp2=static_cast<Base*>(&d2);

    Derived *d1p=static_cast<Derived1*>(bh2);
    Derived *d2p=static_cast<Derived2*>(bp1);

    return 0;
}
```

For example:

```
    Base bp1=static_cast<Base*>(d1);
```

PS: I am sorry if this question doesn't make any sense.

Comment: `d1` has no possible conversion to `Base*` and your code simply won't compile. Maybe you meant `static_cast<Base&>`, in which case the cast is implicit and doesn't add anything.

Comment: Okay! What do you mean by "has no possible conversion to Base*" ?

Comment: Just that. Trying to convert from a `Derived` object to a `Base*` pointer doesn't make sense and the language won't support it. If you want a `Base*` pointer to `d1` you have to take it's address, then the resulting `Derived*` *pointer* can be converted to `Base*`

Comment: Try it. .......

Answer (score 2):

Casting pointers (or references) doesn't do anything to the underlying objects, it just changes how you LOOK at something at the given address (when going through the casted pointer.)  If the cast is invalid, of course your code will have undefined behavior.

Without pointers, you are actually modifying objects.

```
Derived d1;
Base b = d1; // makes a copy of just the "Base" part of d1
```

The above is ok, and needs no cast, but it's not a view of d1 looking like a Base.  It is a sliced off copy of the base part of d1.  "b" is an unrelated object, merely initialized by d.  That is why it's called "slicing".

Casting an object to a pointer is non-sensical, unless your class has a conversion operator to that type, though that would be a generally terrible design:

```
struct Derived : Base {   
    explicit operator Base*() { return this; } // don't really do this, but it compiles
};
```

Given such a weird conversion operator, your cast would work, and it would call Derived::operator Base*.  Because it's explicit, you would need the cast or the conversion would (usually) not happen.  In general, I think you should think about this as mis-matching concepts.  Pointers are not objects; they refer to them.  Doing things to blur that is going to make your program very hard to reason about.